# Using format() with return Query builder object

Tags: php, laravel-4, query-builder

My request SQL is constructed whith query Builder

```
    $candidates = DB::table('candidates')
            ->select('candidates.*')
            ->distinct()
            ->join('candidate_region', 'candidates.id', '=', 'candidate_region.candidate_id')
            ->join('candidate_job', 'candidates.id', '=', 'candidate_job.candidate_id')
            ->whereIn('candidate_region.region_id', $inputs['region'])
            ->whereIn('candidate_job.job_id', $inputs['job'])
            ->where('imavailable', '1')
            ->where('dateDisponible', '<=', $inputs['availableDate'])
            // fait appel à nbSkip() pour calculer le nombre de candidat à passer
            ->skip(Search::nbSkip($_GET['page']))
            // une fois passé le nombre, on prends les 15 suivants
            ->take(15)
            ->get();

    foreach ($paginator as &$candidate) {

        // récupère la liste des jobs
        $candidate->jobs = DB::table('jobs')
                ->join('candidate_job', 'jobs.id', '=', 'candidate_job.job_id')
                ->where('candidate_id', $candidate->id)
                ->get();

        // récupère la liste des régions
        $candidate->regions = DB::table('regions')
                    ->join('candidate_region', 'regions.id', '=', 'candidate_region.region_id')
                    ->where('candidate_id', $candidate->id)
                    ->get();
    }

    // return la liste des candidats
    return $paginator;
```

And i would like use ->format in view candidate.blade.php

dateDisponible = public 'dateDisponible' => string '2011-11-15 00:00:00' (length=19)

```
<div>
    @foreach($candidates as $candidate)
        <p>
            Disponible à partir du/depuis : {{ $candidate->dateDisponible->format('d-m-Y') }}
        </p>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

but i return error : Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any `format` methods in the API. You could instead use `date()` such as

`{{ date("d-m-Y", strtotime($candidate->dateDisponible)) }}`

or use PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

Comment: thanks :) I just wanted to find alternative with the laravel fonction

Comment: No problem.. you can only chain things if the method exists and the caller method returns `$this`.

Answer (score 0):

The format() method come from Carbon class, that is implemented by default in eloquent queries. However,  i'm not sure if is possible use it with Query Builder.